# Desktop doesn't respond after reinstall

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, updates, mouse, desktop-environments

I had to reinstall Ubuntu because of some graphics errors I couldn't handle(based on my research).

I made a Live USB and finished a complete installation. After loading and installing software updates, mouse and system works fine. Some minutes later everything freezes.

An example: I am looking for some apps in ubuntu center, watch files etc, click on settings and then I can't enter anything.

Similar when the mouse or touchpad don't work, but it is not the problem.

I tried 2 more times to install Ubuntu and it is always the same.
I never faced that problem before.

I am asking here from my phone. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: A link to what motherboard you are using and what graphics processor would be useful to correlate you problem to the experience of others.